# How To Make A Sparse File On Android With Terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, android, dd, sparsefile

I'm trying to make a sparse file on android. For this I'm using Android Terminal Emulator. I have installed Busybox so I can use the dd command. Other commands like truncate aren't installed. My question: does anyone know how to make a sparse file with android terminal?

I've tried some commands I found on internet:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/file.img bs=1 count=0 seek="wanted size"
```

But no file would be made. I also tried:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/file.img bs="wanted size" count=1.
```

But I would get the following error:

```
dd "path of if" invalid argument
```

Does anyone know how to get it right?

Comment: Try to be more specific about "some kind of error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already found the answer myself.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/file.img bs=1 count=0 seek="wanted size"
```

Would not make a file since the size on the drive is determined by the block size and count. By setting the count to 0 the file would be 0 bytes and being so, it wouldn't exist.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/file.img bs="wanted size" count=1
```

Would give the following error:

```
dd "path of if" invalid argument
```

The problem here is that there's a limit to the block size. It can't be set that big. I needed to calculate the count for the wanted block size. I chose 64k. This is the working command for making a 512 MB sparse file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/file.img bs=64k count=8192
```

Using seek is optional.

Comment: Using `seek` is *not* optional. What you created is not a *sparse* file at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will create a 5 gigabyte sparse file on my device
`dd of=sparse.img bs=1 count=0 seek=5G`

dd is a program for copying blocks of bytes.
`if=` is used to specify the input file. Not needed here.
`of=` is needed to specify the output file.
`bs=` is needed to specify block size, aka bytes per read or write.
`seek=` is needed to specify the number of output blocks to skip.
`count=` is used to specify the number of blocks to copy.

The default behaviour when `count` isn't specified is to copy the entire input file (which defaults to stdin). `bs` should normally be set to the optimal read/write size of the devices, but in this case setting it to `1` allows us to use human readable numbers for `seek`. Both `seek` and `count` take their values in blocks as defined by `bs` such that `bytes=bs*(count+seek)`.

A sparse file is created using `count=0` and instead using `seek` to set the file size. The accepted answer doesn't create a sparse file at all, instead filling the file with zeros.